# ActionScript 3.0 Changing Direction

Tags: actionscript-3

Alright let me make this clear. I am just doing out of interest. This is not a homework. I am doing it because I am interest in writing the ActionScript. I saw a guy website doing something amazing so I tried to copy and I want to do this:

Oh by the way you need to make a symbol and need to export for ActionScript and class name is "ball". And the button instant name is:bButton. So here's the script I wrote so far.

```
var boundaryRight:Number = stage.stageWidth;
var boundaryLeft:Number = 0;
var balls:Array;
var reverseRight:Number = 0;
var reverseLeft:Number = stage.stageWidth;

init();

function init(){
    balls = new Array();
    for(var i:Number = 0; i<10; i++){
        var myBall:ball = new ball();
        myBall.x=(Math.random()*boundaryRight);
        myBall.y=50+i*40;
        addChild(myBall);
        balls.push(myBall);
    }
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveBall);

function moveBall(e:Event){
    for(var i:Number = 0;i<10;i++){
        var myBall:ball = balls[i];
        myBall.x-=20;
        if(myBall.x<boundaryLeft){
            myBall.x=boundaryRight;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see that code made the multiple ball go to left and looping over and over again. So here's what I want to do. I want to make a button and when I click the button it'll change direction like click and it change direction to right. I click it again and it'll go left again. How do I write the code for that?

Comment: "Oh by the way you need to make a symbol and need to export for ActionScript and class name is "ball". And the button instant name is:bButton." I don't know, if you were trully keen, you have created everything in actionscript. Cough cuogh *homework*, cough cough ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use two global variables direction and speed.

**var direction:Number = 1;
var speed:Number = 20;**

Instead of giving myBall.x-=20;

Give  **myBall.x +=  ( direction * speed );**

In the click handling function of the button

Give  **direction *= -1;**

You can also change speed like this.